# Solutions to the equation $x! + y! = (p-1)^{p}$

Tags: number-theory

So I was messing around with equations involving factorials and I ended up with this:

Find all natural numbers $x,y,p$ where $p$ is a prime such that:
$$x! + y! = (p-1)^{p}$$

Through trial and error the only solutions I could find are $(x,y,p) = (2,3,3), (3,2,3)$ so I'm very interested to know whether or not there exist any other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Just some thoughts here:

ok if $p$ is a prime greater than $2$, then it is odd so $p-1$ must be even, that gives us that:
$$2^p|(p-1)^p$$

---

$$(p-1)^p=(p-1)(p-1)^{p-1}\approx(p-1)e^{p-1}(p-1)!\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(p-1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{p-1}{2\pi}}e^{p-1}(p-1)!$$
where for large $p$ the $(p-1)!$ is the part that will determine the order of magnitude primarily. This shows that $x,p$ or $y,p$ must be of similar orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x \geq y$. Take $q$ to be the smallest prime with the property that $q$ does not divide $p-1$, so that $q \ll \log p$. Then $q$ does not divide $(p-1)^p$ and hence $y < q$. From Stirling's formula, $x > p$ and hence the largest power of $2$ dividing $x!+y!$ is the same as the largest power of $2$ dividing $y!$, and hence bounded above by $y< q \ll \log p$. On the other hand, $2^p \mid (p-1)^p$, a contradiction for larger $p$.

Comment: Why not just say that $q \ll p$ instead of $q \ll \log p$?

Comment: Well, because such a statement would not be strong enough to make this proof work, for starters....

Comment: But where did you use the fact that $q\ll \log p$ in the proof anyway?

Comment: The power of $2$ dividing the LHS is $\ll \log p$ and $\gg p$, so that $p \ll \log p$.